# Redefined MakeExpression leads to error in interpreting

Tags: boxes, interpreter

I’d like to have a `TemplateBox` that interprets as its content boxes:

```
MakeExpression[TemplateBox[{boxes_}, "RawBoxes", ___], form_] := boxes
```

but e.g. the input box `TemplateBox[{"0"}, "RawBoxes"]` refuses to be interpreted leading to

```
Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed .
```

Simplifying the rule to the constant one does not eliminate the error:

```
MakeExpression[TemplateBox[{boxes_}, "Const0", ___], form_] := "0"
```

Evaluating `MakeExpression` explicitly works fine.

This makes me be confused about how interpreting boxes in *Mathematica* works. What do I miss? What am I doing wrong? What is a right way to write ‘MakeExpression’ redefinitions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`MakeExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeExpression) needs to return a [`HoldComplete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldComplete) object. So, the following might do what you want:

```
MakeExpression[TemplateBox[{boxes_}, "RawBoxes", ___], StandardForm] := HoldComplete[boxes]
```

For example:

```
CellPrint @ Cell[
    BoxData @ TemplateBox[
        {RowBox[{"0", "+", "1"}]},
        "RawBoxes",
        DisplayFunction->(#&)
    ],
    "Input"
]
```

[image]

Evaluating the above cell yields:

> RowBox[{"0", "+", "1"}]